# Autoresize UIView in iPhone5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've developed an app for iPhone4 and it works perfectly. But when I open it in iPhone 5, some views have a weird behavior. For example, some spaces are bigger or some elements are bigger, and I don't want that. One of the failures is a screen like the messages app, and the textfield for writing works perfectly in iPhone 4, but in iPhone 5 it is so much bigger. I tried to adjust it with this:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
    NSLog(@"Iphone 5");
    CGRect frameTable = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 454);
    [tableView setFrame:frameTable];

    CGRect frameTextView = CGRectMake(0, 454, 320, 50);
    [textInputView setFrame:frameTextView];
} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
    NSLog(@"Iphone 4");
    CGRect frameTable = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 376);
    [tableView setFrame:frameTable];

    CGRect frameTextView = CGRectMake(0, 376, 320, 50);
    [textInputView setFrame:frameTextView];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the result for your try? Still strange weird behavior?

Comment: With the code that I put, I don't get anything different, same behavior, it doesn't change. I have a .xib, so I think may be I have to change something there...

Comment: You need to set autoresizing behavior correctly. check the size inspector in your xib file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your xib file. Go to 'Identity Inspector' and uncheck the 'Use Autolayout'.